# selenium webdriver with variable

Tags: selenium

Trying to pass the defined variable to element selector, I tried few options, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me ?

```
 def test_04(self):
         driver = self.driver
         spreadsheet = 
         pd.read_excel('SCC_ProdEdit_Page_Top80_Usage_ControlIds.xlsx',
         sheetname='Prod_Edit_Page')
         usernameField = spreadsheet['ControlID'][0]
         username = spreadsheet['ControlID'][1]
         passwordfield = spreadsheet['ControlID'][2]
         password = spreadsheet['ControlID'][3]
         login = spreadsheet['ControlID'][4]
         print(usernameField)
         print(username)
         print(passwordfield)
         print(password)
         print(login)
         self.driver.get("https://stagenext-scc3.foodchainid.com/Login")
         driver.maximize_window()
         driver.find_element_by_id(%s username?? ).send_keys(username ??)


         driver.find_element_by_id(%s username?? ).send_keys(username ??)
```

Comment: If you are trying to interact with an excel spreadsheet, you will not be able to do that with selenium.  If you have a username field in a browser (an element in the DOM) then you can find and interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this by using two different methods, but they require your elements to be unique. I am assuming that in the HTML the ID of the username field is username (id="username")

```
WebElement targetElement = getElementWithId(driver,"username");

    public static WebElement getElementWithId(final SearchContext context, final String idValue) {
        WebElement targetElement = null;

        targetElement = getElementByLocator(context, By.id(idValue));

        return targetElement;
    }


        public static WebElement getElementByLocator(final SearchContext context, final By locator) {
        WebElement targetElement = null;

        try {
            targetElement = context.findElement(locator);
        } // catch selenium exceptions so that the action can act upon the result of the try action.
        catch (final NoSuchElementException e) {
        } catch (final ElementNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (final ElementNotVisibleException e) {
        }

        return targetElement;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain from python

Comment: I created a class that holds a bunch of methods that make selenium easier to use.

Comment: getElementWithId asks you to provide either a WebDriver instance or a WebElement instance, and the String value of the ID tag you are looking for. getElementByLocator converts the String value into the By type that is used to build the findElement call.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it right, you are are not able to pass a variable to find_element_by_id method and send_keys method.
You dont have to use %s. You can directly use the variable name instead as find_element_by_id(username).

Below code worked for me,

```
usernameFieldID = "userName" #spreadsheet['ControlID'][0] This is the id for your username field and only one element exists with this id
username = "test-user" #spreadsheet['ControlID'][1] This as the value (actual username) you have to enter in the user name field.

self.driver.get("https://stagenext-scc3.foodchainid.com/Login")
time.sleep(5) # Just to make sure that the page has loaded before I search for elements. Not relevant to your question.
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_id(usernameFieldID).send_keys(username)
```

If this did not solve you issue, please consider adding more details about the error you are facing.